# React Component env variables from project for imported component

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-package

I have a Create React Project that has some local env variables for config. 
I have a component that uses the env variables to configure itself. It imports the variables using

```
process.env.MY_VAR;
```

I wanted to move the component out into a npm package but retain the ability to use the `process.env.MY_VAR`. When I build and publish the package it will build it with the current `MY_VAR` and not the `MY_VAR` that is in my project I want to import it into. Is there a way I can do what I am after.

I have considered refactoring the component to take the env vars as props, but that's not something I really want to do.

Is there a way I can do what I am after.

Comment: Where do you set your MY_VAR ? Did you use webpack ?

Comment: Have you tried using this one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about treating your component library as a npm package that already is built  fully/independent of build variables and ready to be consumed by npm clients?

Unless you want to use the library as some sort of internal package that naturally has a lot of coupling to the surrounding build environment, it is probably easier to embrace the classic npm approach. And it makes sense especially, if you want to publish the package. In your importing app project, you could still use `process.env.MY_VAR`. For the library part , I would suggest to hand in a configuration object.

If `process.env.MY_VAR` is important for the whole library containing multiple components, start with a package initialization step:

```
import { init } from "my-comp-library"

const config = {
  myVar: process.env.MY_VAR
}

const lib = init(config)
const MyComp = lib.myComp()

const App = () => <MyComp />
```

If only relevant to a single component inside library, you could pass it as props directly:

```
const App = () => <MyComp myVar={process.env.MY_VAR} />
```

In app you could e.g. create a wrapper component `MyAppComp` that already includes its configuration in order to avoid redundant initialization logic for `MyComp`. Additional benefit here is that you would just have one place in app to change code, if library public API changes.

`MyAppComp.js` in app project:

```
import { MyComp } from "my-comp-library"

export const MyAppComp = props => <MyComp myVar={process.env.MY_VAR} {...props} />
```

Independent build management of your app and component project removes coupling, which makes them easier to maintain.

Comment: Yeah that's a pretty good option and seems like a pretty clean solution. How would you handle doing this across multiple screens in my importing app? That seems like I would be doing a lot of initialisations. Any suggestions?

Comment: I like this. I like it a lot :D Nice

Comment: Cool (-:  , glad it helps.

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you created project via create-react-app then you can use [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) npm package.
 If you have webpack then you can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package as well. In alternative way you may use below code to define the variable.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
}),
```